# Pig: Joining without nested renaming

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig

I have two datasets

```
 A(af1, af2, af3)
 B(bf1, bf2, bf3)
```

When I join them in Pig as

```
 C = Join A by af1, B by bf1
```

And subsequently store as a JSON (after removing the join-predicate column)

```
 store C into 'output.son' using JsonStorage();
```

I see a JSON schema as

```
 {"A::af1":val, "A::af2":val, ...., "B::bf2":val, ...}
```

Is there a way I can strip off the unnecessary (as I am taking care of the ambiguity already) nesting-like naming resulting from the join?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We have to iterate over relation/alias C and generate the required fields and then store the new alias, lets say new alias is D.

```
 D = FOREACH C GENERATE A::af1  AS af1, A::af2 AS af2, A::af3 AS af3, B::bf2 AS bf2, B::bf3 AS bf3;

STORE D INTO 'output.son' USING JsonStorage();
```

**Update :**

If there are 100 of unique field names in alias A, likewise in B, then after join we can use .. operator and select the required columns. We can even access the required fields using position notation also ($0..$99,$101..$200)

```
  C = JOIN A BY af1, B BY bf1;

  D = FOREACH C GENERATE af1..af100,bf2..bf100;
  STORE D INTO 'output.son' USING JsonStorage();
```

Comment: I agree with your procedure in general. But that's kind of impossible for in my case, (a) the schema tree is extremely wide (there are thousands of fields in stay, `B`) and, (b) more importantly, it is dynamic.

Comment: @NikhilJJoshi: Another alternative is to make use of .. operator. Updated the answer.